# How to protect Web API in Angular client app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an Angular application where the anonymous user fills forms, do payment and purchase product (and there is no user login form ).
Angular application uses a Web Api written in Asp .net core in order retrieve and store form data.

As I do not have user login form and I have a Client side angular application.
How do I secure the Web Api endpoints ?

Answer (score 2):

*anonymous user fills forms* != *How do I secure the Web Api endpoints* thats kind of two opposite things. Sure you can do some stuff to "improve security" but it wont help if you need to serve anonymous users.

There are few things you can do on backend:

1. Use CORS in prod
2. Use services like recaptcha
3. Use bot detection services
4. Use rate limit from single IP
5. Use HTTPS

But again without proper user sign in there is no way you can make it secure. And lastly security should always be done on server side, anything you do for security in Angular is more just for UX/UI